# TCP windows scale option not used event if buffer size updated

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp, yocto

I have a python program that receive data over TCP from a microcontroller.
I need to increase TCP receive buffer so I tried to use TCP windows scaling factor.

TCP windows scaling is enabled :

`net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1`

I set a bigger default buffer size in sysctl.conf :

```
net.core.wmem_max=4194304
net.core.rmem_max=12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 2097152 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 2097152 4194304
```

If I check windows size in my python code i get the right size :

```
>>> import socket
>>> server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> print(server.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF))
2097152
```

But in wireshark it seems windows scale factor is not used:

Window size value: 11152

[Calculated window size: 11152]

**[Window size scaling factor: -2 (no window scaling used)]**

And after some time my receive buffer is full :

```
[TCP Window Full] 61902 → 7600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=18267709 Ack=51 Win=16800 Len=760
[TCP ZeroWindow] 7600 → 61902 [ACK] Seq=51 Ack=18268469 Win=0 Len=0
[TCP Dup ACK 15#1] 61902 → 7600 [ACK] Seq=18268469 Ack=51 Win=16800 Len=0
[TCP Window Update] 7600 → 61902 [ACK] Seq=51 Ack=18268469 Win=65535 Len=0
```

Any idea why the scaling factor is not used ?

**Setup versions :**

Python version : 3.8.2

Toradex Linux Yocto with 5.4 kernel

On microcontroller side I use Microchip TCP/IP stack with SAMV71 custom board.

Comment: Look at the 3 way handshake where the scaling factor is negotiated.  Perhaps the microcontroller's tcp stack does not support window scaling.

Comment: The microcontroller don't support TCP windows scaling. Should it be supported by both sides to be used ? I only want to increase the buffer size on the receiving end. The thing is that even if I just do "wget" on another machine, TCP windows scaling is not used and if I wget from my laptop, I see that TCP windows scaling is used.

Comment: If the micro-controller doesn't support window scaling there is no way for you to tell the micro-controller that your window is greater than 65535 = 2^16-1.